# How to get isodate string from bson date/time object or timestamp with python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

When converting bson date/time objects to json, using bson json_util, the datetime is represented as millisecs since epoch.

Is there a way to convert the date/time to isodate string instead?  Or is the better way to convert the datetime instance to string before using json_util to dump json?

```
raw cursor item: {u'_id': ObjectId('4fc51500381b472cfdfa4eaf'), u'ts': datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 29, 18, 27, 12, 221000)}
```

json.dumps(obj, default=json_util.default)

```
json: {"_id": {"$oid": "4fc51500381b472cfdfa4eaf"},"ts": {"$date": 1338316032221}}
```

When using python datetime module datetime.fromtimestamp(ts) I got ValueError, am I doing something wrong?:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1338316032221)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: year is out of range
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You give the `fromtimestamp` method the time since epoch in milliseconds, but it expects time since epoch in *seconds* (see [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) and [time.time](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time) documentation) :)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem myself with Python and MongoDB storage. The simplest answer is:

```
import time
bson_timevalue = 1421147432935
readable_date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", time.localtime(int(bson_timevalue / 1000)))

print readable_date
```

Gives you: `2015-01-13`